# Google Maps Infobox mouseleave event doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using an alternative to the Google Maps InfoWindow called [InfoBox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/).

I want the InfoBox to close on mouseleave and I've managed to do this with the following code, but altough it works in Firefox and Opera, I get no result in Chrome.

```
var markerinfo = new InfoBox({disableAutoPan: true, isHidden: false, pane: 'floatPane', enableEventPropagation : true});

  // addListener to show infobox and set its content with #infobox id on marker click here //

google.maps.event.addListener(markerinfo,'domready', function(e){
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('infobox),'mouseleave', function(marker,content,infobox){
     return function() {
       infobox.close(map,marker);
     }
   }(marker,content,markerinfo)); 
});
```

This works fine in Firefox and Opera but not in Chrome (26.0.1410.63)

Any leads on how can I fix this or alternative ways to accomplish this?